# does typescript with webpack tree shaking work with es5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

i have a module which is javascript ES5 module called `phaser`. It also contains type declarations.

In my `main.ts` file, i have

`import * as phaser from 'phaser'`

If i build it using webpack, (I am using ts-loader for module rules in webpack), What happens is the final output doesn't contain `phaser` at all. If i add `console.log(phaser)` to my file, then the build output contains `phaser library`.

**Question**: Seems like because of I don't use `phaser` , tree shaking works, but why?  I am asking because, `phaser` is written in ES5,so even though i am importing it as ES6, tree shaking still shouldn't work. A good example of this is that if I change `main.ts to main.js` and have only importing statement as i have above, even though I don't `console.log(phaser)`, the final build will contain `phaser` . Looks like it's something related to `ts-loader or tsconfig.json?` Any ideas? I have empty `tsconfig.json` not to complicate things.